# Set app icon does not work properly (winform)

Tags: winforms

I need to set the icon as an app icon, so I can see it at the header of main form. In order to do it

1. I got my icon in `.ico` format
2. I choose needed project, right click Properties
3. Application -> Icon and manifest
4. Browse needed icon
5. Run the project

I really see that icon was updated in toolbox (footer) I mean at the bottom of the screen I see updated icon, but in my form I still see the old one.

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Form has Icon, set the Form Icon using the properties window.

[image]